# Module 'firebase_core' not found flutter sample dynamic link test project

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

Im testing firebase dynamic links on a sample project to implement it on a project I'm working on. I have created a sample flutter project, created a dynamic link , set assosiate domain set up everything works fine and the link can open my app no problem.

Next task I wanted to test out was use flutter firebase_dynamic_links 2.0.6 package follow all the instructions no issue in the android studio end but as soon as I add this dependencies and I start getting this error 'Module 'firebase_core' not found' in 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m'

only thing I did was add pod 'Firebase/Analytics' in the podlike , and add firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.6 to dependencies to a sample flutter app that auto generate.

I tried opening Runner.xcworkspace , clear flutter and rebuild iOS .I even tried 'pod deintegrate' and 'pod install' (this was mentioned on a forum when I looked for an answer) hope this clear what I have tried so far and if I missed something please let me know ,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

issue was the version issues with cocoapods. ran up sudo gem install cocoapods --pre and everything was fixed